# How to minimize spectral radius in this situation?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I have a Hermitian matrix $A$ ($A^{\dagger} = A$), and a diagonal real matrix $B$.

Now I need to minimize $$\rho(A - B)$$ ($\rho(\cdot)$ is the spectral radius), 
when the diagonal elements of $B$ can change under the condition that $$tr(A - B) = 0.$$

Could someone offer an approach?

Answer (score 0):

I have made the calculations for $2\times 2$ matrices, maybe it helps you to solve the general problem.

Let $A=\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b\\ b & c\end{array}\right)$ be a Hermitian matrix and let
$B=\left( \begin{array}{cc} s & 0\\ 0 & t\end{array}\right)$ be such that $tr(A-B)=0$. Since $tr(A)=a+c$ and $tr(B)=s+t$ we conclude that $s=a+c-t$. Hence
$$A-B=\left( \begin{array}{cc} t-c & b\\ b & c-t\end{array}\right).$$
The eigenvalues of $A-B$ are
$$ \lambda_{1,2}=\pm \sqrt{(t-c)^2+b^2}$$
which gives
$$ \rho(A-B)=\sqrt{(t-c)^2+b^2}. $$
Of course, the minimal possible value of $\rho(A-B)$ is $|b|$, we get it if 
$B=\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & 0\\ 0 & c\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you. But I think the 2-dimensional situation can not be extended to the general case. I have tried letting the diagonal elements be zero, but numerical results showed the spectral radius is not the smallest in this situation.